solr search from nested object
I am using solr as search engine and saving some details as nested child object
field type is text-general

available_from_date and available_to_date is timestamp
i am trying to get details based on available_adults ,available_children, available_from_date, available_to_date
if user entered date is between any of this timestamp and adults with available_adults  >= some values, then i need to fetch the parent row
the query which i tried is
{!parent which="*:* -_nest_path_:*" v=$q.nest} &q.nest = available_adults:[6 TO *] & available_from_date [1726790400 TO *]

but it is not giving the correct result
Can some one please help on this as i am new to solr
